# what is the use of keeping reference of an object as static in Java?

Tags: java, object, reference, static

As per my understanding any static method or member belongs to whole class so that all instances of that class can share that common resource however in many places I have seen that programmer keep object reference as static while creating an object. I'm not able to understand this. Any explanation in this context will enhance my understanding. Thank you

Comment: Please provide a code example of the specific code pattern that you're interested in?

Comment: as you said, so this object, referenced by this static field, will be accesible from all instances of that class (or, technically from any place allowed by visibility settings)

Comment: I suggest you read the source for some of the common classes in `java.lang` and `java.util` and you will see examples of this and many other common patterns which are really used.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyGrinev , got it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sure will do thanks.

Comment: @PrabhatSinghYadav In your IDE you should be able to `<ctrl>+<click>` to jumpt to the source of any class, including those in the JDK.

Comment: The use of a static declaration is to match a model where the member is associated with the type as a whole and not any particular instance.